# Ошибка при импорте модуля - Python + Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Возникает такая ошибка, когда пытаюсь создать OPENAPI.JSON

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 633, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 629, in main
    args.callback(args)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 487, in _GenOpenApiSpecCallback
    application_path=args.application)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 332, in _GenOpenApiSpec
    application_path=application_path)
  File "lib/endpoints/endpointscfg.py", line 183, in GenApiConfig
    module = __import__(module_name, fromlist=base_service_class_name)
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import endpoints
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/endpoints/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from apiserving import *
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/endpoints/apiserving.py", line 75, in <module>
    from google.api.control import wsgi as control_wsgi
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/google/api/control/wsgi.py", line 37, in <module>
    from google.api.auth import suppliers, tokens
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/google/api/auth/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.api.auth import suppliers
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/google/api/auth/suppliers.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jwkest import jwk
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/jwkest/jwk.py", line 11, in <module>
    from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 78, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/home/injection/PycharmProjects/CRM-GAE/lib/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import OSRNG
ImportError: cannot import name OSRNG
```

Либа Crypto и pycrypto стоят. В чем проблема может быть.
Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в доках, Google App Engine поддерживает `pycrypto` - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 обратите внимание на версии